# Is std::random_device cryptographic secure?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, cryptography

I see many people talk about security and `std::random_device` together.

For example, [here](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http%3A%2F%2Fvideo.ch9.ms%2Fsessions%2Fgonat%2F2013%2FSTLGN13rand.pptx) slide 22.

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device), `std::random_device` :

> std::random_device is a uniformly-distributed integer random number generator that produces non-deterministic random numbers.

It does not talk about security explicitly.

Is there any valid reference that explicitly mentions `std::random_device` is secure for cryptography?

Comment: I can't speak for the quality of the product in the security sense (https://security.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place to go to get the opinions of security experts) but `random_device` is allowed to fall back on a deterministic value if a non-deterministic generator is unavailable, rendering it not that effective. Check your platform and toolchain for full support.

Comment: `std::random_device` gives no *guarantees* - its specification is so weak as to be essentially useless as a 'portable' CSPRNG.

Comment: I believe the CPP Reference page is wrong. According to [P0205R0 - Allow Seeding Random Number Engines with std::random_device](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0205r0.html): *"The standard library provides the type std::random_device (§ 26.5.6 [rand.device]), a uniform random number generator (§ 26.5.1.3 [rand.req.urng]) that is supposed (but, unfortunately, not required) to produce a non-deterministic sequence of uniformly distributed integers of type unsigned int."* Its been my experience non-determinism is a tricky/hard property.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, because that's not what `std::random_device` is designed for; it's designed to generate random numbers, not to be secure.

In the context of security, randomness is something that is useful for key generation, but randomness is not something that is absolutely needed. For example, [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) does not use any randomness, yet AES-256 is what is used to encrypt top secret information in the US.

One area where randomness and security cross, is when a random key is generated and used; if I can guess the seed and know the random protocol used, there's a good chance I can then use that same seed value to generate the same "random" value and thus the same key.

[`std::random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) will use a hardware module (like a hardware [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module)) if one is available, otherwise it will use whatever the OS has as a RNG (like [`CryptGenRandom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942(v=vs.85).aspx) in Windows, or [`/dev/random`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev/random) in *nix systems), which might even be a PRNG (pseudo-random number generator), which might generate the same number depending on the random number algorithm used. As a side note: much like how the [AES instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) was incorporated into chipsets to speed up encryption and decryption, [hardware RNG's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator) help to give a larger entropy pool and faster random number generation as the algorithms are moved into hardware.

So if you are using `std::random_device` in any sort of cryptographic key generation, you'll need to be aware what random number generator is being used on the system being deployed to, otherwise you can have collisions and thus your encrypted system can be susceptible to duplicate key types of attack.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214670/discussion-on-answer-by-txtechhelp-is-stdrandom-device-cryptographic-secure).

Comment: AES does NOT work without cryptographically-secure random number generators. long trail of of CERT advisories to that effect started in the late 70s, and will probably continue onward to the heat death of the universe.  Keys have to be derived from a cryptographically secure random number generator.

Comment: @RobinDavies .. AES is an algorithm that uses block ciphers to encrypt/decrypt data. No part of the AES algorithm itself uses any random generation. Hence my statement that AES does not use any randomness. You are correct that a sufficiently random key is necessary, but more importantly a sufficiently long enough key is necessary to avoid brute-force attacks (entropy and all that), especially if we're talking about data in transit versus data at rest. So yes, AES does, in fact, _work_ without a cryptographic secure RNG, it just opens your data to potential brute force or side-channel attacks

Comment: Pedantically differentiating between "works", and "works securely". <shrugs>

Comment: @RobinDavies being pedantic is extremely important in Engineering and Science. If you're not, you're doing it wrong ;)

Comment: Pretty sure the right pedantic distinction is "Does not work securely.". If you failed to make that distinction, you're DEFINITELY doing it wrong. ;-)

Comment: @RobinDavies whatever you say.

Comment: The `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` as well as the `CryptGenRandom` use a **seeded** CSPRNG which is about as secure as it gets. Yes, you should make sure that the system is capable of seeding itself, but that's the case for **any** RNG. Although the answer dives deeper afterwards, the initial "No" is definitely not warranted in my opinion.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes .. the "No" is because the question is asking about if there's any valid reference to `std::random_device` being secure for cryptography; there is not. `std::random_device` is designed to generate random numbers which is a completely different context from "security". Also, the `P` in CSPRNG means "pseudo", and "as secure as it gets" is not secure when pseudo is involved; especially given that there are hardware RNG's built in to many systems (e.g. AES-NI). So understanding which RNG is being called by `std::random_device` on the target platform is important for "security".

Comment: @txtechhelp I do agree that the definition / documentation of `std::random_device` is wanting if you require a CSPRNG, and that it matters how it is implemented on specific runtimes. I do not agree about the statements about CSPRNG's: a well seeded CSPRNG is fine as a source of random values, and arguably better than a raw, non-whitened entropy  source. Actually RDRAND uses an AES based CSPRNG (which is based on AES-NI, so they are certainly related but not the same).

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: only use `std::random_device` to generate seeds for the defined PRNG's within this library. Otherwise use a cryptographic library such as Crypto++, Bothan, OpenSSL etc. to generate secure random numbers.

---

To have an idea why `std::random_device` is required it is important to see it in the light of the context for which it was defined.

`std::random_device` is part of a [set of classes and methods that are used to generate deterministic/pseudo random number sequences *fast*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). One example - also shown in the slides - is the Mersenne twister algorithm, which is certainly not cryptographically secure.

Now this is all very nice, but as the defined algorithms are all deterministic, this is arguably not what the users may be after: they want a fast random number generator that doesn't produce the same stream all of the time. Some kind of entropy source is required to **seed** the insecure PRNG. This is where `std::random_device` comes into action, it is used to seed the Mersenne twister (as shown in the slides referred to in the answer).

The slides show a speed difference of about 250 times for the Mersenne twister and the slow system provided non-deterministic random number generator. This clearly demonstrates why local, deterministic PRNG's can help to speed up random number generation.

Also note that local PRNG's won't slow down much when used from multiple threads. The system generator *could* be speedy when accessed by multiple threads, but this is certainly not a given. Sometimes system RNG's may even block or have latency or related issues.

---

As mentioned in the comments below the question, the contract for `std::random_device` is rather weak. It talks about using a "deterministic" generator if a system generator is not avialable. Of course, on most desktop / server configurations such a device (e.g. `/dev/random` or the non-blocking `/dev/urandom` device) **is** available. In that case `std:random_device` is rather likely to return a secure random number generator. However, you cannot **rely** on this to happen on all system configurations.

If you require a relatively fast **secure** random number generator I would recommend you use a cryptographic library such as OpenSSL or Crypto++ instead of using an insecure fast one the relatively slow system random generator. OpenSSL - for instance - will use the system random generator (as well as other entropy sources) to seed a more secure algorithm.

Comment: Also see [P0205R0 - Allow Seeding Random Number Engines with std::random_device](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0205r0.html) (ISO submission) and [D0205R1 - Final draft for "Allow Seeding Random Number Engines with std::random_device"](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/i1B6bfwjwic) (ISO future proposal).

Comment: I agree with what you said, but a side note: local PRNGs can be secure (modulo memory protection) and also fast, e.g. ChaCha. The system generator is slow partly because of the system call overhead. Also, Mersenne Twister is neither fast *nor* good quality compared to modern PRNGs, and uses a *lot* of memory.

Comment: I think this answer would be much more useful if contains some sample codes.

Comment: @kelalaka I'll have to check up on the context again, and see if manual seeding of the fast, non secure PRNG's using the `std:random_device` is required.